# Если я сделал imageview как кнопку, то как сделать анимацию затемнения?

Tags: android

Как можно реализовать анимацию затемнения, при нажатии на imageview, как кнопку?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте эту либу: [Material Ripple Layout](https://github.com/balysv/material-ripple)

```
MaterialRippleLayout.on(view)
       .rippleColor(Color.BLACK)
       .create();
```